# Heart Attack Risk Score calculation

Tags: cardiology, prevention, cardiovascular-disease

Someone recently mentionned to me a score to calculate my risk of having a heart attack in the next years.

Unfortunately he was not able to tell me where I could access this tool (or is this just for medical professionals?)

Could you help me on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for the the risk score assessment tool based on the Framingham Heart Study.

It predicts a person’s risk of having a heart attack in the next 10 years. 
It takes into account your age, gender, total cholesterol, HDL cholesterol, systolic blood pressure and smoking status. So you will need information concerning your lipid profile.

You can find the score calculator tool on this link:

http://cvdrisk.nhlbi.nih.gov/

This is the most commonly used. Depending on your gender or ethnicity, there might be other scores. Some suggest the Reynolds score if you are a woman (http://www.reynoldsriskscore.org/). If you are in Europe, some prefer using the SCORE Risk chart (http://www.escardio.org/Guidelines-&-Education/Practice-tools/CVD-prevention-toolbox/SCORE-Risk-Charts). In the UK, the QRISK2 score is also frequently used (https://www.qrisk.org/).

Comment: Excellent! That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @S.Victor, sorry to be picky here (though +1 for providing different tools for different ethnies/group of patients), but "it predicts a person's chance of having a heart attack" --> is this really a chance? :-p Maybe it would be worth considering changing to "it predicts a person's risk of having a heart attack"? Best regards. M Arrowsmith

Comment: Indeed, risk would fit better in this context! I have edited my answer. BW